# Send array items to server or query it on the server side?

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb

This is my scenario and I am trying to do what is more efficient.

I have a user with an array of followers ranging from 100-5000 followers (much more or a bit less than the min). The user and follower count is stored locally on the users device (Android - sqlite).

Option A: When a user wants to see his followers I send a request to the servers (node.js) of the userId to be queried (mongodb) then another query for all the users in the followers array of that user.

Option B: Have the user send a request with the userId and the array of follower ids, and just make one query to the server to find the followers.

Effects of A: Double the query (since the followers array has to be queried first)

Effects of B: Connection can be lost and data would have to be resent, and can be a large amount of data to send at once, would have to call a POST/PUT as oppose to a GET (at least I think I do).

Factors:
-User Experience - priority 1
-Server Costs - priority 2

**EDIT**

Clarifications:

This is referring to one user, and his followers. I have the followers ids stored in rows in sqlite from when it was sent upon Login.

Comment: I'm confused (1) in Option A "his followers" - his is the user who is holding the phone? or one user in the phone holder's followers list? (2) What exactly is stored in the SQLite db? is it list of user ids for all followers? Or just a count of followers?

Comment: How did you get the ids of the followers on the device in the first place?

Comment: I added clarifications above... the user holding the phone, and a list of all the userIds (so a row for each id)... @Benito I store it upon login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why are you even sending the follower ids in the first place?**

There is no point in sending the follower ids in the login response.

Let's consider this is your current login response:

```
{
  status:"success"
  data: {
          userId: "123456",
          firstName: "John",
          lastName: "Doe",
          followers: [ "111111", "222222", "333333", ... ]
        }
}
```

So you save the follower ids. Now how would you use them?

You can't request a single follower profile since you didn't send the names, and you wouldn't show the user a list of follower ids to choose from, because he wouldn't know which follower they are selecting.

So you have to at least add a follower name to each id, which would mean a very large response, considering a user can have up to 5000 followers.

This is too much for a login API, in my opinion (even without the names).

Alternatively you could just send the number of followers.

```
{
  status:"success"
  data: {
          userId: "123456",
          firstName: "John",
          lastName: "Doe",
          followerCount: 2000
        }
}
```

Now when the user decides to see his followers, you can just send his user id (option A), which is enough to query them.

I'm not familiar with document-oriented databases, but I don't suppose such a query would have any performance issues.

**Why not option B?**

1. As stated before the login API response would be very large.
2. What if the user followers changed between the login and the second API? You wouldn't have the user Id of a new follower, for example.

**One last piece of advice**

Implement server-side paging in your response.

5000 is a pretty big number. Your response will be huge without paging and some device might not have enough memory to store it.

Here's an example:

http://www.example.com/followers?userId=123456&pageSize=25

```
{
  status:"success"
  data: {
          followers: [
              {
                userId: "----",
                userName: "----",
                firstName: "----",
                lastName: "----",
                ImageUrl: "----"  
              },     
              {
                userId: "----",
                userName: "----",
                firstName: "----",
                lastName: "----",
                ImageUrl: "----"  
              }, 

             ...     
          ]
          paging: {
              page: 1, 
              pageSize: 25,
              previous: "",
              next:"http://www.example.com/followers?userId=123456&pageSize=25&page=2"
          }
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks great post, I was saving the ids to see if user(A) for example, would visit another user's profile (B), i would request a query search for (B) only and then I would check if (A) has (B)'s user id stored in the sqlitedb - if so then he is following him if not then he can follow him and that would be added into his list of people to follow in sqlite instead of querying the db for (B) and then (A) and seeing if (B)'s id matches a list of following matches of an id in (A)'s array... and then for everytime the user decides to add or remove (B) I do not have to keep making a request.

Comment: However, I guess I can just include new follows/unfollows only and maybe just send over if it is <100 followers/following... how do I associate the page number with the user count?

Comment: Regarding your first comment, when you request another user's profile, you can send a boolean value isFollower which indicates whether this user is a follower or not.

Comment: You don't have to associate the page number with user count. I just added it for display purposes: " You have 2000 followers".

Comment: Oh ok, and each page = 100 user IDs for example, and pull out user 0-100, is that how you go about it, and if it hits a certain number call page 2 with some formula getting the range 100-200? Because cant I just add the total count or something and divide it by a 100, and then ask for each index range based on just count, just wondering how it works since I will be actually doing it on android when a user pulls and hits close to 100 I have it call for more

Comment: And just to clarify the isFollower, then on every profile page I will make a second db request and return a boolean value, based on the id being present in the user's followers array?

Comment: You can do exactly as you say: `page = count / pagesize`.

Comment: Regarding the extra db request, since I'm not familiar with document-oriented dbs I can't answer that. For relational dbs you can get the user info and check if he is a follower in the same query.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this efficiently I'd implement a cache-key that you store in mongodb and the android device. Whenever a person's followers change, the cache key is regenerated. The key is indexed in mongodb to make lookups quick.

When I want to look at one of my followers I send the follower ID and the cache key. If the key matches, the device has the most recent data so you can send back a "chache valid" response. If it doesn't match, the device needs refreshed. An indexed lookup for only the cache key will be very quick.

Comment: awesome, yeah I was just thinking about that, the only thing is regardless I would have to grab the data from mongodb since I am only storing the rows of userid in the table (since it will take too much space to store every users thumbnail and  information)

Comment: So I am thinking maybe just send the cache regardless anyways to know whether a refresh needs to happen.

Comment: If I am actually recording the changes of the actions done by users... I do not need a cache key because it can be assumed that I have the latest data since anyways I am updating it every day and on major calls to the db